# Check Database for any new entries for a given time period after backup

Tags: php, mysql

Yesterday I took a backup of a live database because I'm switching hosting providers. I have roughly 200 tables in my database. I want to find out if any new data was added to any table since the time I took my backup. Is there an easy way to do this? I'm using Phpmyadmin and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Export database...

and compare with any software like beyond compare you will see extra insert statement ...

Comment: you can do it live with pt-sync-table